# Iterative inorder traversal in Swift incorrect answer

Tags: swift

There is a pseudocode implementation here: https://algorithms.tutorialhorizon.com/inorder-traversal-non-recursive-approach/ of a iterative inorder that I've implemented in Swift.

Pseudo Code:

> Create a Stack. Push the root into the stack and set the root =
>   root.left continue till it hits the NULL. If root is null and Stack is
>   empty Then return, we are done. Else Pop the top Node from the Stack
>   and set it as, root = popped_Node. print the root and go right, root =
>   root.right. Go to step 2. End If

However I'm getting the last element repeated.

My inorder:

```
func inOrderDFSIterative() -> [Int] {
    var s = [self]
    var curr : Node? = self
    var outputArr: [Int] = []

    while !s.isEmpty    {
        // reach the leftmost node of the current Node
        while curr != nil {
            s.append(curr!)
            curr = curr!.left
        }
        curr = s.popLast()!
        outputArr.append(curr!.data)
        curr = curr?.right
    }
    return outputArr
}
```

Which is part of my binary tree class

```
class Node: Hashable {
    static func == (lhs: Node, rhs: Node) -> Bool {
        return lhs.data == rhs.data
    }
    var hashValue: Int {
        return data
    }

    var data : Int
    var left : Node? = nil
    var right : Node? = nil

    init(_ data : Int) {
        self.data = data
    }

    func insert (_ data : Int) {
        if data < self.data {
            if let lft = left {
                lft.insert(data)
            } else {
                let newNode = Node(data)
                left = newNode
            }
        } else {
            if let rgt = right {
                rgt.insert(data)
            } else {
                let newNode = Node(data)
                right = newNode
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've set up a tree

```
let regularTree = Node(20)
regularTree.insert(8)
regularTree.insert(4)
regularTree.insert(12)
regularTree.insert(10)
regularTree.insert(14)
regularTree.insert(22)
```

and regularTree.inOrderDFSIterative() returns rather than [4, 8, 10, 12, 14, 20, 22, 20] instead of [4, 8, 10, 12, 14, 20, 22]
Which is obviously incorrect. What is the problem here?

Answer (score 1):

Check that `s` is not empty before appending `curr!.data` to `outputArr`:

```
curr = s.popLast()!
if !s.isEmpty {
    outputArr.append(curr!.data)
    curr = curr?.right
}
```

---

Generally speaking, avoid force-unwrapping, and use more *Swifty* ways like optional binding or the `guard` construct:

```
while !s.isEmpty    {
    // reach the leftmost node of the current Node
    while let current = curr {
        s.append(current)
        curr = current.left
    }
    curr = s.popLast()
    if !s.isEmpty, let current = curr {
        outputArr.append(current.data)
        curr = current.right
    }
}
```